# Add the Hour of backup SQL Server command in Batchfile

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, backup

I want to make every hour a backup of 1 database in SQL Server via a Windows Batch file.

The hour should be processed in the filename.

```
sqlcmd -S SRV01 -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [databasename] TO DISK = N'C:\Backup\databasename\hourly_%HOUR%.BAK'"
```

Howto solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the hour, you can use the environment variable *`%time%`* that is perfect for this task.

You will need to extract the hour from *`%time%`* because it has format `hh:mm:ss,cs`

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%T in ("%time%") do set "hour=%%T"
```

So the final command (assuming you are running both commands in the same batch file) for SQL Server will be

```
sqlcmd -S SRV01 -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [databasename] TO DISK = N'C:\Backup\databasename\hourly_%HOUR%.BAK'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you  to take a look at that article [Multiple methods for scheduling a SQL Server backup automatically](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-methods-for-scheduling-a-sql-server-backup-automatically/). On that article you can see how to use widgets to set where you want to save your backups as well as schedule when it will be initialized.